# Manually calculating quantum circuit with custom gate

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit, matrix-representation, quirk

I am trying to calculate the state of this Quirk circuit by hand:

[image]

where U is a custom gate with 2x2 matrix:

[image]

From what I've read, I should be able to calculate the resultant amplitudes as:

**(U⊗I⊗I).(anti_controlled_H⊗I).(anti_Toffoli)**

which is

[image: calculation]

But the resulting amplitudes in Wolfram Alpha do not match the Quirk output, leading me to believe I've made fundamental mistake. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

While quantum circuits are written such that time goes left to right<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_circuit)</sup>, matrix multiplication goes the other direction<sup>[[2]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)</sup>.

That is, a quantum circuit contains the gate $U_1$ followed by $U_2$ is equivalent to $U_2U_1$.

Which means you need to calculate
$(\text{Anti-CCX})(\text{Anti-CH} \otimes I)(U \otimes I \otimes I)$